# closing a window pop up on button click opened using window.open()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, browser

I want to create another window when user clicks open button. This window will contain contents if a div. Also it'll have a close button. On click of the close button I want to close this popped up window.

When we click on open it opens the `<div id="myContent">` 
in another window, but after opening it, I want it to close that window using close button.

```js
document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var newWindowContent = document.getElementById("myContent").innerHTML;
  var newWindow = window.open("", "", "width=500,height=400");
  newWindow.document.write(newWindowContent);
});
```

```html
<article type="text" id="editor" contenteditable="true">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum ad eos, facere ipsam odio dignissimos voluptatibus dolor sunt qui ipsum, quos praesentium doloribus nulla mollitia laboriosam expedita maxime, asperiores consequuntur?
</article>
<h1>Open the element content when click the button</h1>
<div id="myContent">
  <button id="mybtnn">close</button> This is the content that will be inside the new popup window
</div>
<button id="mybtn">open</button>
```

Comment: Just use `window.close()` in the click of the button. Also you need to close the document when you have finished writing to it `newWindow.document.write(newWindowContent); newWindow.document.close();`

but why not just show a new div in a modal dialog, then you will not have to worry about browsers not allowing a new window

Comment: @mplungjan He needs to close the new window from "inside" of the new window, so it's just window.close

Comment: @Nikolay he ALSO needs to CLOSE the DOCUMENT at time of writing, or the page is in an unstable state. window.close and document.close are not related

Comment: Anyway this is a dupe

Answer (score 1):

You can use [window.close](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp)

```html
<button id="mybtnn" onclick="window.close()">close</button>
```